# eslint rule to require a specific prop for a react component?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eslint, typescript-eslint, eslintrc

I am using a 3p component library that I cannot modify. However, I want to always require a specific component prop when it's used in a form. Here's an example:

```
<div className="my-header-actions">
  <CustomButton /> // This is fine
  <CustomButton someProp="wizbang" /> // This is fine
</div>
```

```
<form>
  <CustomButton someProp="wizbang" /> // This is fine
  <CustomButton /> // This should error & require someProp
</form>
```

In the example above, how can I create eslint config that will require `someProp` only when used inside a form like this?

Comment: Is doing it with typescript an option for you?

Comment: I am trying to accomplish this as a lint rule specifically

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using the [no-restricted-syntax](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-syntax) rule:

```js
"no-restricted-syntax": [
    "error",
    {
        selector:
            "JSXElement[openingElement.name.name='CustomButton']:not(:has(JSXAttribute[name.name='someProp']))",
        message:
            'You must pass `someProp` when creating a <CustomButton>.'
    }
]
```